# How to reload apache in php-apache docker container via shell_exec?

Tags: php, apache, docker

I created multiple vhost and needed to reload the apache to make the vhost available, however `shell_exec('service apache2 reload')` didn't seem to work inside the container.

From my understanding is php-apache ([link](https://hub.docker.com/_/php)) container runs under www-data user therefore it doesn't have permission to trigger the sudo command. So is there anyway to shell_exec a sudo command.

FYI guys, this question is regarding to docker container environment not a normal Linux. Basically I can do all these commands under normal apache in the host machine, however I want to experiment it in docker container. Ultimately, I would try all the other sudo commands such as a2ensite, a2dissite, etc...

Any thought? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't restarting the wole container not a solution?

Comment: Restarting the whole container will affect the other vhost.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't to this directly, if your script is running under Apache. Your script hasn't enough rights to make such a command.

Anyway, I think that it's a **very dangerous idea** to give to your script the rights to use sudo, through Apache.

But, you can let an information in your database or a server's file. And then, let a script to reload Apache via a superuser's [crontab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), by example, if the information is found.

Example code :

```
<?php
if ($something_append) {
    // let an information in the server.
    touch('/srv/have_to_reload_apache') ;
}
?>
```

The superuser's cron : (could be a `sh` script or whatever)

```
sudo crontab -e
```

write :

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/sudo_script.php
```

This will run the script every 5 minutes.
The script could be :

```
<?php
if (file_exists('/srv/have_to_reload_apache')) {
    shell_exec('service apache2 reload'); // Reload apache
    unlink('/srv/have_to_reload_apache'); // Remove information
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very highly discouraged, regarding security.

If you know what you are doing, usage in a locale private network, filtering user data, you can add php, or a full user as root to the sudoers file with the tool **visudo**.

```
sudo visudo
```

This way php won't ask for passwords at all.

Your scripts needs then to be called with sudo, so it can contain **shell_exec** sudo commands

```
sudo ./script.php
```

Adding a full user is also more than highly insecured, but **from my view** it is also very good for dev/*hack* and learning. It's good to know how this works and play around , to later focus on security.

It permit to create scratch system applications with powerful powers and their web interface.

In the sudoers file, add:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: DNSRELOAD
```

This is highly used in private research environment.

See the sudoers manual: https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html

A very similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110931/using-sudoers-to-allow-php-to-run-command

Comment: This solution is perfectly fine if apache is installed in the host machine but it is container env and visudo isn't available to modify

Comment: You probably need then to create a privileged container, run it as root. This seems doable with LXC container https://linuxcontainers.org/fr/lxc/getting-started/ , sorry i didn't saw you was using docker.

Comment: I had make a tool in php to allow this kind of stuff, maybe it can help you, at least give some idea: https://github.com/webdev23/shakti