# Shell code not executing with PHP

Tags: php, shell

How can I get the following code to work with PHP:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec("service mysql restart");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

When I load the page on my server, nothing happens.

I need my users to be able to restart mysql server with an easy script, since it keeps crashing on DigitalOcean for an unknown reason...

Comment: Maybe have a look to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242291/how-to-reload-apache-in-php-apache-docker-container-via-shell-exec/48242352#48242352

Comment: Slightly random question.. Are your users running wordpress?

Comment: @Dale Yes, why?

Comment: I have some wordpress sites and some custom coded ones on the same server.

Comment: This may shed some light on your situation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-keeps-crashing-error-establishing-a-database-connection

Comment: And this may help with a solution https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: PHP can use shell_exec on server? Try with other command

Comment: Im suggesting these solutions because, if you go down the road of allowing your web server to restart your database server, you need to give access to the webserver user (www-data?) to your database which I really don't like the sound of

Comment: Ok I'll try this out and let you know if it fixes the issue, thanks

Comment: @AdamStrudwick Any luck?